# progid filter isn't running

Tags: css, sprite, css-sprites

I'm using a `filter` to the older `IE` on my `sprite`, so I used the `filters`. 
The code below isn't working. I know I made a mistake I don't know wich one / where:-/ 
On `Chrome` it's ok, the properties is disabled but in `IE`, the `background-size` isn't working.

If I disable the "`background-size`" in `Chrome`, I see the same BAD screen as in

```css
.icones { 
    background: transparent url('../contents/homepage/60/icones.png') no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 48px;
    background-size: 60px;

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../contents/homepage/60/icones.png',sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../contents/homepage/60/icones.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
}

#contact{
    background-position: 0px -350px;
}
```

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background-size: 60px; wasn't applied on IE, so I deletes this line and I made a picture of 60px. This solved my question.